# Gunicorn returns "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list" when testing Django site in Ubuntu server

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04) tutorial on DigitalOcean for the setup of a Django site. After initial setup and migrations, when I test the usual `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` it works well (showing all images and grabbing all static files) with no errors.

When I test `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi`, no static files are grabbed (anyway, I understand that's Nginx's job) but this error appears for every static file requested in the page:

```
Internal Server Error: /static/img/logos/TSG-logo.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tsg/buses/busesenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/tsg/buses/busesenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/tsg/buses/busesenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 36, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
  File "/home/tsg/buses/busesenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 76, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

I suspect this is related to `settings.py`, where `STATICFILES_DIRS` are declared as a list, [according](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) to Django:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
```

This doesn't look to me related to `collectstatic` (but it could be).

Why is it that there is no error in the Django server and when Gunicorn is used suddenly the **list of paths** is a problem?

I'm using Python 3.8.10, Django 3.2.5, gunicorn 20.1.0 and nginx 1.18.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you have not posted full error traceback, yet i notice another issue in your code.

`STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILE_DIRS` should not be the same folder.
By the way, i have you may notice i added `staticfiles folder which will be automatically created when you run the` collectstatic` commands.

Try this and let me know if it works

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Thanks @anamul for pointing that out! It certainly solves one issue with `collectstatic`. The "TypeError" is still there, though. I have updated the full error traceback and added your suggestion. Cheers.

Comment: Can you add your requirement.txt file?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem.
And finally, solve it.
It's just I made a silly mistake:
I wrote the path in the file .bashrc as:

```
export PATH="/home/HEPTools//lhapdf6_py3/bin:$PATH".
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home//LHAPDF/lib/python3.9/site-packages"
```

The path is written wrong.
I wrote "//" not the correct "/".
Hope this helps.